# Using JPA criteria API to select with pattern

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

My code snippet:

```
criteriaQuery.select(root);
Predicate ctfPredicate;

if (deptPattern.contains("%") || deptPattern.contains("_")) {
    deptPattern = deptPattern.replaceAll("%", "^%").replaceAll("_", "^_");
}
System.out.println("case sensitive  " +deptPattern);
ctfPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like((Expression)root.get("name"), "%" + deptPattern + "%", '^');            

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(ctfPredicate));

TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = entitymanager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Object> resultlist = typedQuery.getResultList();
printResult(resultlist);
```

The resultList does not return anything, whereas db has 2 entries with dname Sales.
Query getting printed :
select department0_.deptno as deptno0_, department0_.loc as loc0_, department0_.dname as dname0_ from mydept department0_ where department0_.dname like ? escape ?

Database used is Oracle and JPA2.0 vendor is EclipseLink

Comment: What does this line print? `System.out.println("case sensitive  " +deptPattern);`

Comment: case sensitive  Sales^%

Comment: Check the size of `resultlist`, perhaps method name is `resultlist.getSize();`

Answer (score 0):

The db had entries with name as Sales, without %. 
And the input pattern was given as 'Sales%'. I changed it to 'Sales', since the code was adding '%' to the input.
And the result list returned both the entries.

Comment: Does this mean you are getting the correct or expected results?